# using array write a program that tests the randomness of the computer's random number generator

Tags: eclipse

How can i write a program that tests the randomness of the computer's random number generator.Generate 10,000 integers in the rage 0 to 9 and display a list of the counts for each number at the end. Since there is a 1 in 10 chance for each number, there should be about 1000 of each when done.Alla this is using array

example of output

0's: 1007

1's: 1024

2's: 989

...

Comment: First, choose a language..

Comment: "Eclipse" is not a language. It is an IDE, in which you can write in many languages.   Also, Stack Overflow isn't the place to teach you how to write code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need a random number generator. There is no rng inside you PC that delivers "real" random numbers. There are certain algorithms, that produce pseudo random numbers after being seeded (in c++ theres rand(), which is a linear congruential generator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator, or if using c++11 there are more sophisticated alternatives like a mersenne twister http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).

When testing the "randomness" of those algorithms you could do it experimentally your proposal is sufficient when creating uniform distributed random numbers. A more generalized approach would be to compute the difference of the integrals of the experimental result and the target distribution of random numbers. Although when knowing the algorithm its probably more efficient to analyse it analytically to find out its periodicity.

Since I didn't read a question I am none the less hoping that I've answered it.